# Как реализовать bcrypt на android

Tags: android, android-sdk, безопасность

С помощь чего можно делать bcryp хэш на android?

Answer (score 2):

Например, есть библиотека [jBcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/):

```
// Hash a password for the first time
String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());

// gensalt's log_rounds parameter determines the complexity
// the work factor is 2**log_rounds, and the default is 10
String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(12));

// Check that an unencrypted password matches one that has
// previously been hashed
if (BCrypt.checkpw(candidate, hashed))
    System.out.println("It matches");
else
    System.out.println("It does not match");
```

Главное не забывать, что вычисление хеша довольно ресурсоёмкая операция, и не вычислять его в UI-thread.

Comment: Спасибо. Символы для публикации)